# Sound normalization gain for music files on Linux (via bs1770gain)

Tags: audio

I want to normalize (increase sound level) in music files (mostly mp3s). That issue been discussed before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/166298/is-there-a-program-that-edits-audio-files-to-have-the-same-volume

However, on recent distributions previously most common software (mp3gain) is no longer available in repositories and does not compile etc: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391446 and been replaced with `bs1770gain`. I installed it and tried, however, the result is not as expected, it produced for some reason **flacs** out of mp3s with noticeably **quieter** sound, not gained one and man pages, help and page with archive (though I installed via apt on Linux Mint) https://sourceforge.net/projects/bs1770gain/files/bs1770gain does not show clearly how to do staff mp3gain was capable of.

How to use `bs1770gain` same way as `mp3gain` was used? Alternatively working way to run `mp3gain` on (preferably) Ubuntu based Linux?

Comment: FWIW, bs1770gain's main developer (pbelkner) has been very helpful and quick to reply to my recent e-mails. You may want to contact him directly in case you have more questions (I won't post his e-mail address here to prevent spam but you can find it on SourceForge).

Answer (score 2):

***Disclaimer:** My system does not meet the requirements of current BS1770GAIN 0.6.5, so my answer is based solely on its documentation.*

> it produced for some reason flacs out of mp3s

Which option you are using? `-o` or `-ao`?

- **Supplying `-o` *without `-a`* is the correct action** for non-transcoding uses (i.e. adding *ReplayGain* tag).
- `-a` (apply) means change the actual audio data to match the target loudness; ReplayGain-style metadata will *not* be written in this case.

  - This option forces transcoding, which default to libre-lossless FLAC codec unless `--suffix` option is given. (`--suffix` is available since 0.6.0 beta 20, circa 27-Jun-2019)

> with noticeably **quieter** sound

If the original audio is severely compressed to a very high loudness level (i.e. victim of [loudness war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war)); then it is possible, and intended, that the normalized output will be quieter. Some of my files got "-11 dB" ReplayGain tag after it got through `mp3gain` program.

But in case of BS1770GAIN, this might be a side effect of **correct normalization to a *wrong standard***: see note 1 for details, and note 2 for remedy.

> How to use `bs1770gain` same way as `mp3gain` was used?

Not exactly; since `bs1770gain`, as far as documentation states, does not update MP3 files in-place like `mp3gain` did. The nearest usage is supposed to be as follow:

```
bs1770gain -o OUTPUT --replaygain SOURCE
```

- `SOURCE` can be single input MP3 file, multiple input MP3 files, or a director containing multiple input MP3 files.
- `OUTPUT` is target directory for writing output file(s) to.

#### Notes

1. By default, `bs1770gain` targets loudness of European broadcaster's EBU R128 specification, which is 5 dB *quieter* than ReplayGain.
2. The `--replaygain` option sets target loudness to the one from [ReplayGain 2.0 draft specification](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=ReplayGain_2.0_specification).
3. ReplayGain 2.0 targets the same loudness as [ReplayGain 1.0 specification](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=ReplayGain_1.0_specification), but utilizes the improved ITU BS.1770 algorithm for measuring original tracks.
4. [`mp3gain`](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/) is based on ReplayGain 1.0 specification.

#### Alternative

If you would like to use ReplayGain 1.0 algorithm, and/or ability to update MP3 files in-place— maybe consider using [`replaygain` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/replaygain.1.html) instead. (It is provided by ["python-rgain" package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-rgain); and available in latest non-LTS Ubuntu too)